# Maven exploded war to jboss deploy dir

Tags: java, maven-2, jboss

I'm currently using maven war plugin to deploy my war to jboss dir :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>basic</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>${jboss.home}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I do mvn clean install this deploys my war to jboss dir, but when trying to combine it with exploded war maven shell command `mvn clean prepare-package war:exploded` my exploded war doesn't get deployed to jboss deploy directory.

Is it possible to have exploded war deployed to jboss directory directly from maven, rather than creating seperate script to copy exploded war dir from target to jboss deploy dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Maven War plugin - Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) page

The default directory for the exploded WAR is `target/<finalName>`. This default directory can be overridden by specifying the `webappDirectory` parameter.

You could adding `<webappDirectory>${jboss.home}</webappDirectory>` to `<configuration>` and see if it works.

Comment: it coppies contents of exploded war(WEB-INF etc.) to jboss dir, so then I created my appname.war in jboss deploy directory and updated jboss.home variable to point to jboss.home/appname.war and the files are directly exploded there. In short it works, thank you

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct approach. <webappDirectory> is the directory where the webapp is BUILT. so for example when you want to create a war file and explode it at the same time, the second operation is performed first, then the contents of that directory are packed into the war. but there is no clean phase before build, so if you happen to "forget" something unnecessary in that deploy directory, it gets packaged in the final war, which can cause a lot of trouble. you can still do manual clean before build but anything else than the target directory should be deleted with extra care.